# Calculating height for AVL tree while inserting node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have verified in three sources for avl insert code. In all the cases to calculate height,

> root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left), 
>                               self.getHeight(root.right))

the above line is given.

Here is my query, why should we take max of both left and right subtree and add one to that?
What if we are adding the node to the subtree with minimum height? In that case both will have same height **H** not **H+1**.

This increment of height should be added as,

```
 elif key < root.key:    
      root.left = self.insertNode(root.left, key)  
      root.height = 1 + self.getHeight(root.left)
 else:    
      root.right = self.insertNode(root.right, key)
      root.height = 1 + self.getHeight(root.right )
```

Am I correct? If yes, why these people are adding one after taking max?

Please use the full code for verification below. code is taken from programiz.com. Also verified geek for geeks.

```
def insertNode(self, root, key): 

        if not root: 
            return TreeNode(key) 
        elif key < root.key: 
            root.left = self.insertNode(root.left, key) 
        else: 
            root.right = self.insertNode(root.right, key) 

        root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left), 
                        self.getHeight(root.right)) 

        balanceFactor = self.getBalance(root) 

        if balanceFactor > 1:
            if key < root.left.key: 
                return self.rightRotate(root) 
            else:
                root.left = self.leftRotate(root.left) 
                return self.rightRotate(root)

        if balanceFactor < -1:
            if key > root.right.key: 
                return self.leftRotate(root)
            else:
                root.right = self.rightRotate(root.right) 
                return self.leftRotate(root)

        return root
```

Comment: `self.getHeight(root.left)` looks object-disoriented.

Comment: I just wonder... You say you have verified in three sources for avl insert code and in all three cases they calculate height. WHY...? As far as I know, the height is not needed in an AVL tree, it runs with a balance indicator alone. Also in the code you quote the `height` is calculated but never used. So why is it calculated? It seems just a waste of time....

Comment: Minor expansion: It seems just a waste of time to calculate the height and a waste of space to store it in a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a tree like this:

```
       5
      / \
     /   \
    3     7
   /     / \
  2     6   8
             \
              9
```

The tree has a height of 3 (there are 3 branches between the root node 5 and the deepest leaf node 9).

The subtrees' heights are 1 for the left one (rooted at the node 3) and 2 for the right one (rooted at 7), and

```
3 = H(node(5)) = 1 + max(H(node(3)), H(node(7))) = 1 + max(1, 2)
```

Now suppose you add a node with a key 4 to the tree:

```
       5
      / \
     /   \
    3     7
   / \   / \
  2   4 6   8
             \
              9
```

The height of the tree rooted at node 3 did not increase: H(node(3)) still equals 1.

If you do a proposed replacement in the algorithm, your tree will erroneously get a height of 2 after a described insertion: `1 + H(node(3))`, instead of keeping the height equal 3.

**IF** your code has been **actually 'verified'** by any programming site, then run away from that site and never trust them again.

Comment: I have a query regarding this avl vs red-black tree. What is the maximum rotation needed by avl tree? I can see maximum of two rotation is enough to balance a tree in all examples. Then what is the need of red black trees? The advantage over red-black tree is faster insertions/deletion because of fewer rotations. So What is the maximum rotation needed by avl tree and What is the maximum rotation needed by red black tree?

Comment: @Gokulakannan I think this should be asked as a separate question, first because it does not expand the problem discussed here, second because I do not know the answer. Anyway you'll need to make your question more specific. For example, specify if you are asking about trees with a given height or with given number of nodes; if it is about an average case or the worst case; whether an average is taken over all possible shapes of a tree or all positions of insertion...? Also whether you are interested in a single insertion or in building a tree from a set of data; etc...